# Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. Stuck with an example, can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

I am pretty sure I am missing something somewhere but I cannot see where and have been stuck for a while... Like in the example I set the first vector $U_1$ to \begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    1\\
    0\\
    \end{pmatrix} and then, its orthogonal vector, $U_2$ as $x_1 - \frac{U_1^T U_1}{||U_1||} x_1$.

My issue is evaluating the second term, in that I get a vector that is not orthogonal to \begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    1\\
    0\\
    \end{pmatrix}

I am attempting to show my working here:
$U_2 =$
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{pmatrix} - {{2}^{1/2}}\begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

This gives me $$\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 + {2}^{1/2}\\
    0\\
    1- {2}^{1/2}\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$ which when I take the dot product with my original $U_1$, does not give 0 and is hence not orthogonal. Apologies for the mess as I am not accustomed to the formatting. Would really appreciate some help.

[image]

Comment: Assuming that $U_1$ is the **normalised** first vector, then compute $x_2-(U_1^T x_2) U_1 = (-{1 \over 2}, -{1 \over 2}, 1)^T$.

Comment: You need to draw a little picture of the geometry to see what you are doing. Just subtracting a multiple of $U_1$ from itself has no relation whatsoever to $x_2$.

Comment: @copper.hat I had the picture in mind and had done it well but what I missed, which you first pointed out was making sure $U_1$ was normalised. Thank you so much!